# TypeError tratando de armar un stack

Tags: python, stack

Hola soy nuevo en python y estoy tratando de armar una clase para manejar un  stack, pero me sale **TypeError** cuando uso el método Push

```
class Queue:
def __init__(self):
    self.push = []
    self.pop = []

def push(self, x):
    self.push = x
    
    
def pop(self):
    if self.push == []:
        raise IndexError('pop from an empty queue')
    else:
        self.pop.append(self.push.pop(0))
```

Comment: Tienes un atributos y una clase que se llaman igual, cambia el nombre de uno

Comment: Además al hacer `push` estas asignando a una variable, que en principio era una lista, una sola variable que puede ser cualquier cosa, lo ideal es añadir eso a la fila y no reemplazar y borrar toda la fila. Eso también podría ocasionar el error ya que `self.push` deja de ser una lista y deja de tener sus métodos de lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Es un stack o una cola? Supongamos que quieres un stack:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = []

    def push(self, elemento):
        self._stack.append(elemento)

    def pop(self):
        if len(self._stack) == 0:
            raise ValueError

        return self._stack.pop()
```

El stack se implementa con una lista, que hace fácil implementar `push`: es cosa de hacer un `append` a la lista.

El `pop` requiere verificar que haya algo que sacar del stack. Si está vacio, el método genera una excepción `ValueError`.

#### Demo

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stack = []

    def push(self, elemento):
        self._stack.append(elemento)

    def pop(self):
        if len(self._stack) == 0:
            raise ValueError

        return self._stack.pop()

st = Stack()
st.push("1")
st.push("2")
st.push("3")
print(st.pop())
print(st.pop())
print(st.pop())
print(st.pop())
```

produce:

```
3
2
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_8.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(st.pop())
  File "/home/candid/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/scratch_8.py", line 10, in pop
    raise ValueError
ValueError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Como pusimos tres valores en el stack y luego sacamos cuatro, en el último intento se produjo una excepción.

#### Cola

Si en lugar de un stack quieres implementar una cola (queue), es cosa de cambiar

```
    return self._stack.pop()
```

en el método `pop()` por

```
    return self._stack.pop(0)
```

Comment: Gracias porque se pudo evitar el error "not callable" y funciona bien.  Efectivamente corresponde a una cola y se elimina el primer elemento como lo detallaste.  Sin embargo me dicen en las instrucciones que debo resolverlo con dos slacks.. es decir debo pasar al usar el método pop e irlo alimentando en forma inversa. Sin embargo no le hallo mucho sentido...